# Sencha Touch - add KeyDown event on NumberField

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2.3

I've been banging my head against the wall for days trying to get a KeyPress or a KeyDown event to fire on a Sencha Touch textfield.

I'm trying to accomplish two things:
1) Limit the max length to 3 and
2) Ensure that the user is entering only numbers (no letters or special chars)

Is there no way using Javascript to attach these events?  I'm using Sencha 2.3.1

Update: I've tried using numberfield and also using maxLength...neither work.

```
   var numberfield = 
    {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        value: textValue,
        readOnly: true,
        cls: 'opBuyoffPartialCell',
        inputCls: 'opBuyoffCenterText',
        maxLength: 3,
        enforceMaxLength: 3
    };
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a [numberfield](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number) component instead of a textfield, with a maxLength of 3?

Answer (score 0):

As @MonicaOlejniczak wrote, use a [numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number).

If you don't want to use a numberfield, at least have a look at its code and find that Sencha uses

```
this.getComponent().input.dom.setAttribute("type", "number");
```

to ensure that the user can only input numbers. That way, the "number" `,,,`, which your code would allow, will also be taken care of.

To ensure a `maxLength`, sencha already has [`maxLength` config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number-cfg-maxLength) which is available on both the numberfield and the textfield.

Comment: Sadly using a numberfield does not prevent the user from entering letters.  Also, I've tried using maxLength - and it doesn't seem to have any effect on the number of allowed entries.  I've pasted my updated code above.